# Ramda: condition statement issue

Tags: conditional-statements, ramda.js

I tried to set a condition statement using R.cond. Firstly, i got the array size according to the input (i.e. [1,2,3]), then check if the array size is greater / equal to the input size (i.e. 3). But i got an error message. I would like to know why the error occur and how to fix it, thanks.

```
R.cond([
  [R.compose(R.gte, R.length), () => {console.log(1)}],
  [R.T, () => {console.log(2)}]
])([1,2,3])(3)
```

Error message: R.cond(...)(...) is not a function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there are two separate issues here.  First of all, because the vast majority of calls to `cond`-functions are unary, it does not curry the result.

So you cannot call it as `(...)([1,2,3])(3)`.  You will need to do `(...)([1,2,3], 3)`.

But that won't fix the other issue.

`compose` (and its twin `pipe`) do take multiple arguments for their first call, but after that only a single argument is passed between them.  So the only value being passed to `gte` is the result of `length`.

You can fix this in several ways.  Perhaps the simplest is:

```
const fn = R.cond([
  [(list, len) => list.length >= len, always(1)],
  [R.T, always(2)]
]);

fn([1, 2], 3); //=> 2
fn([1, 2, 3], 3); //=> 1
```

(Note that I changed your `console.log` to a function that returns a value.)

If you want to make this points-free, you could switch to use Ramda's [`useWith`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#useWith) like this:

```
const fn = R.cond([
  [R.useWith(R.gte, [R.length, R.identity]), always(1)],
  [R.T, always(2)]
]);
```

But as often happens, I think the introduction of arrow functions makes tools like `useWith` less helpful.  I find the earlier version more readable.

You can see these in action on the **[Ramda REPL](http://ramdajs.com/repl/?v=0.23.0#?const%20fn1%20%3D%20R.cond%28%5B%0A%20%20%5BR.compose%28R.gte%2C%20R.length%29%2C%20always%281%29%5D%2C%0A%20%20%5BR.T%2C%20always%282%29%5D%0A%5D%29%3B%0A%0Afn1%28%5B1%2C%202%5D%2C%203%29%3B%20%2F%2F%3D%3E%201%0Afn1%28%5B1%2C%202%2C%203%5D%2C%203%29%3B%20%2F%2F%3D%3E%201%0A%0Aconst%20fn2%20%3D%20R.cond%28%5B%0A%20%20%5B%28list%2C%20len%29%20%3D%3E%20list.length%20%3E%3D%20len%2C%20always%281%29%5D%2C%0A%20%20%5BR.T%2C%20always%282%29%5D%0A%5D%29%3B%0A%0Afn2%28%5B1%2C%202%5D%2C%203%29%3B%20%2F%2F%3D%3E%202%0Afn2%28%5B1%2C%202%2C%203%5D%2C%203%29%3B%20%2F%2F%3D%3E%201%0A%0A%0Aconst%20fn3%20%3D%20R.cond%28%5B%0A%20%20%5BR.useWith%28R.gte%2C%20%5BR.length%2C%20R.identity%5D%29%2C%20always%281%29%5D%2C%0A%20%20%5BR.T%2C%20always%282%29%5D%0A%5D%29%3B%0A%0Afn3%28%5B1%2C%202%5D%2C%203%29%3B%20%2F%2F%3D%3E%202%0Afn3%28%5B1%2C%202%2C%203%5D%2C%203%29%3B%20%2F%2F%3D%3E%201%0A)**.

Comment: Thank you, very useful.

Comment: Excuse me, i want to ask more about your example in Ramda REPL. We call fn1([1, 2], 3) and the result return 1. The program should do  R.length([1,2]) and get the result 2, then do R.gte(2), am i right? If yes, the result of R.gte(2) is a function, why it return 1 instead of 2? Thanks.

Comment: Because `cond` checks whether something is truthy.  So `gte(2)` is a function, and it's truthy, we return the consequent of the first condition.  (Note for instance, that `!!(function() {}); //=> true`.)